# How do I get .NET redirects to work with an API deployed to an Azure API Management Service with a URL suffix?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, http, redirect

I have several APIs which are made available by an Azure API Management Service.

The API Management Service has a domain and each API has its own "API URL Suffix" setup in the Azure portal like below:

- API 1: https://www.example.com/first
- API 2: https://www.example.com/second
- API 3: https://www.example.com/third

The problem is that when any of these APIs performs a redirect using the `Redirect` or `RedirectToAction` methods, it doesn't include the "API URL Suffix" in the new URL and this causes Azure to return a 404 error.

e.g.

A call to

```
https://www.example.com/first/api/v1/controller/action
```

that should redirect to

```
https://www.example.com/first/api/v1/controller/redirected
```

actually redirects to

```
https://www.example.com/api/v1/controller/redirected
```

which can't be found.

I don't know if this is an Azure problem, a coding problem, or an HTTP problem.

Do relative Location headers only take the domain into account when redirecting and nothing that follows the domain?

Should I just hard code the "API URL Suffix" in the `Redirect` and `RedirectToAction` calls?

Would I have to setup some sort of proxy for my development environment then to add the suffix before the actual routes when testing?

Would I have to manually make sure both the code and the Azure settings are in sync?

Or is there some sort of Azure setting that will fix this so I redirects will actually work with an "API URL Suffix"?

Or is there any other kind of workaround for this? Is there some ugly string manipulation I would have to do using the request URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the policy in API Management:

[Rewrite URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL)

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <rewrite-uri template="/v2/US/hardware/{storenumber}&{ordernumber}?City=city&State=state" />
</inbound>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
```